# Prove TRUE is derivable (or provable) from the Empty Set (Ex 3, Sec 1.4 in "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Rautenberg.)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

I've being trying to understand more about logic. My reference book is "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Wolfgang Rautenberg. Now I'm having troubles with exercise 3 in section 1.4. In the solutions to the exercises is stated that the following easily follows from the $\lnot$ - rules:

$\vdash\top$

$\lnot \alpha \vdash \lnot (\alpha \land \beta)$

Well, not so easy for me. If you can please help. Thanks

Comment: Hey! Could you cite the whole exercise?

Answer (score 2):

$\bot$ is defined as a contradiction, namely: $(p_1 ∧ ¬p_1)$ and $\top$ is defined as $\lnot \bot$ (see page 5).

The proof of the first one:

1) $\lnot \bot \vdash \lnot \bot$ --- by (IS)

2) $\bot \vdash p_1 \land \lnot p_1$ --- by abbreviation

3) $\bot \vdash p_1,\lnot p_1$ --- by ($\land_2$)

4) $\bot \vdash \lnot \bot$ --- by ($\lnot_1$)

> 5) $\vdash \lnot \bot$ --- from 1) and 4) by ($\lnot_2$), i.e. $\vdash \top$.

---

For the second one:

1) $\lnot \alpha, \lnot (\alpha \land \beta) \vdash \lnot (\alpha \land \beta)$ --- by (IS) and (MR)

2) $\lnot \alpha, \alpha \land \beta \vdash \lnot (\alpha \land \beta)$ --- by (IS), (MR), ($\land_2$) and ($\lnot_1$)

> 3) $\lnot \alpha \vdash \lnot (\alpha \land \beta)$ --- by ($\lnot_2$).