# Doesn't $\vdash \alpha \Rightarrow \vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha$ imply the inconsistency of $\vdash$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading Wolfgang Rautenberg's "A concise Introcuction to Mathematical Logic", on the hints of question 3 from section 3.4 (to prove that a finitary consequence relation $\vdash$ satisfying Gentzen type rules is maximally consistent) (http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/raut/logic3/hint.pdf), and using calculus of the Gentzen type for propositional logic the author claims:
$$
\vdash \alpha \Rightarrow \vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha
$$
My attempt was:

$$
\vdash \alpha \Rightarrow \lnot \alpha, \lnot \lnot \alpha \vdash \alpha, \text{ by the monotonicity rule}\\ \Rightarrow \lnot \alpha, \lnot \lnot \alpha \vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha \\\Rightarrow \vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha
$$

but a similar argument could also prove $\vdash \beta$ for all $\beta$ substituting $\lnot \lnot \alpha$ by $\beta$ in the second implication. This would prove the inconsistency of $\vdash$ wich does'nt make sense to me. Is my proof of the claim correct? Does it matter that assuming $\vdash \alpha$ one can prove the inconsistency of $\vdash$? How could one prove such a claim if my proof is incorrect?

EDIT: I found out my proof is incorrect in the last implication, it does not follow from any rule. So how can we prove $\vdash \alpha \Rightarrow \vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha$?

Comment: Why so? In propositional logic (check with truth table) $\alpha \equiv \lnot \lnot \alpha$

Comment: When you replace $\alpha$ with $\beta$ what you get is: $\beta \equiv \lnot \lnot \beta$. What is the issue with it?

Comment: Because there must be a purely syntatic derivation of $\vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha$.

Comment: ... provided that you start from a derivation $\vdash \alpha$.

Comment: Exactly so there is a purely syntatic derivation of $\vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha$ using Gentzen type rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we have a derivation $\vdash \alpha$, then we we get the derivation
$$
\dfrac{
 \neg \alpha \vdash \neg \alpha 
 \hspace{4em}  
 \neg \alpha \vdash \alpha
}
{\dfrac
{\neg \alpha \vdash \bot} 
{\vdash \neg \neg \alpha}
}
$$
where we first used the $\mathsf{C^-}$ rule (Lemma 4.2), and the left branch is done by the *initial sequent* rule, whereas the right branch has a derivation by assumption.

Comment: +1 Good idea! The only issue is that Ruatenberg's system has $\lnot$ as primitive and $\bot$ is defined as $p_0 \land \lnot p_0$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Indeed I agree! I just had a look at the book trying to see the rules he uses (section 1.4 *A Calculus of Natural Deduction*) and they seem a bit odd to me (the 2 rules for $\land$ seem circular?). But I will try to fix it only using his rules.

Comment: I agree - there are a couple (Rautenberg, Ebbinghaus: German !) authors who use strange versione of hybrid ND/Sequent calculus that lose all the beauty and simplicity of original Gentzen's ...

Comment: Altough I just noticed he says somewhere in the text that *"$X \vdash \alpha, \beta$ is to mean $X \vdash \alpha$ and $X \vdash \beta$"*

Answer (score 3):

No inconsistency at all (in classical propositional logic we have: $α≡¬¬α$).

The result does **not** assert that we have a derivation of $⊢¬¬α$, but that

> we have a derivation of $¬¬α$, provided that we have a derivation of $α$.

Consider a simple example: we cannot use the result above to conclude that in arithmetic we have a (terrible) proof of $¬¬(0=1)$, but the (much more innocent):

> "if we have a proof of $(0=1)$, then we have a proof of $¬¬(0=1)$".

---

Regarding

> "but a similar argument could also prove $⊢β$ for all $β$ substituting $¬¬α$ by $β$ in the second implication",

there is no issue. You have to replace $α$ by $β$ in the overall argument and nothing change: we have no "$\vdash \lnot \lnot \beta$, from which $\vdash \beta$", but again: "if $\vdash \beta$, then ...".

---

---

To the EDIT:

> $(\text {DN}_1) \ \ \vdash \lnot \lnot B \to B$

1. $\lnot \lnot B \vdash \lnot \lnot B$ --- (initial)
2. $\lnot B, \lnot \lnot B \vdash \lnot \lnot B$ --- (MR)
3. $\lnot B \vdash \lnot B$ --- (initial)

> 4. $\lnot \lnot B \vdash B$ --- (2,3, reductio).

---

> $(\text {DN}_2) \ \ B \to \lnot \lnot B$

1. $\lnot \lnot \lnot B \vdash \lnot B$ --- $(\text {DN}_1)$
2. $B \vdash B$ --- (initial)
3. $\lnot \lnot \lnot B, B \vdash B$ --- (MR)
4. $B \vdash \lnot \lnot B$ --- (2,3, reductio).

---

Thus, if we have $\vdash \alpha$, we have also $\vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha$ by $(\text {DN}_2)$.

Comment: I understood your arguments, but what I am looking for is a derivation of the type you made in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528917/prove-true-is-derivable-or-provable-from-the-empty-set-ex-3-sec-1-4-in-a-co?rq=1, how can one derive, $\vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha$ from $\vdash \alpha$?